# definition of essential annulus contained in the boundary

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, manifolds-with-boundary

I read John Hempel's paper "3-manifolds viewed from the curve complex". In the proof of Theorem 3.2, he calls annuli in the boundary of a solid torus essential.
(see picture below from his article).

[image]

All definitions that I find of essential annulus requiring that the annulus is properly embedded. Hence, the definitions do not make sense.

> Let $M$ be a 3-manifold with boundary. Let $A$ be an annulus in $\partial M$.
>   What does it for $A$ mean to be essential?

Comment: This would make more sense if you reproduced the entire quote from Hempel's book, namely the place where "he calls annuli in the boundary of a solid torus essential".

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for your comment. I added a picture containing the part of the proof.